# What is the derivative of this function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Would any one tell me what is the $\partial^2U/\partial X^2$ where $$U(X,Z)=\frac{1}{W(Z)}\psi\left(\frac{X-X_c(Z)}{W(Z)},\xi(Z)\right)e^{i\phi(X,Z)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $U(X,W)=R(X,W)\cdot S(X,W)$ with
$$
R(X,W)=W^{-1}\,\psi(W^{-1}(X-X_c(W)),\xi(Z)),\qquad S(X,W)=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi(X,Z)}
$$
one gets
$$
\partial_{11}^2U=\partial_{11}^2R\cdot S+2\partial_{1}R\cdot\partial_1S+R\cdot\partial_{11}^2S,
$$
with
$$
\partial_{1}R=W^{-2}\,\partial_{1}\psi(W^{-1}(X-X_c(W)),\xi(Z)),
$$
$$
\partial_{11}^2R=W^{-3}\,\partial_{11}^2\psi(W^{-1}(X-X_c(W)),\xi(Z)),
$$
and
$$
\partial_1S=\mathrm i\partial_1\phi\cdot S,\qquad\partial_{11}^2S=(\mathrm i\partial_{11}^2-(\partial_1\phi)^2)\cdot S.
$$